# How to create non-virtual navigation property from EDMX?

Tags: entity-framework

By default, all the navigation properties created from EDMX are marked as `virtual ICollection<...>`.

Is it possible to eager load one of the navigation properties? Like,

```
public partial class Applicant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; set; }
}
```

In this way, I will be able to have `ContactInfo` in the interface.

```
public interface IApplicant
{
     int Id { get; set; }
     ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; set; }
}

public partial class Applicant : IApplicant
{
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Navigation properties can't be configured to be eager loading. Only `Include` does that, irrespective of the property being virtual or not.

Comment: So there is no way to have navigation property in the interface, isn't it?

Comment: Of course you can define the interface, but it has nothing to do with loading behavior. You're connecting two unrelated concepts.